# Как правильно провести запрос с переменными в mysqli средствами php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$token = $_COOKIE['login']; //токен аккаунта отправителя
$uname = $_GET['username']; //никнейм получателя
$transfer = $_GET['transfer']; //сколько отправить
$link = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database); //подключается, всё нормально
$query = "SET @a = (SELECT `coins` FROM `users` WHERE `token`='".$token."');@b = (SELECT `coins` FROM `users` WHERE `username`='".$uname."'); UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=@b+".$transfer." WHERE `username`='".$uname."';UPDATE `users` SET `coins`=@a-".$transfer." WHERE `token`='".$token."'"; //запрос производится, пишет что запрос проведён успешно, но результата нету
        $try = mysqli_multi_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link)); //ошибок не даёт
```

> **Задача**:
>
> Считать кол-во монеток отправителя (переменная **@a**), кол-во монеток получателя (переменная **@b**), изменить значение @a на **@a - $transfer**, а значение @b+ на **@b + $transfer**.

Где моя ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста...

Comment: Блин, сам решил....
Запрос должен выглядеть так :  
`$query = "UPDATE \`users\` SET \`coins\`=(SELECT \`coins\` WHERE \`username\`='".$uname."')+".$transfer." WHERE \`username\`='".$uname."';UPDATE \`users\` SET \`coins\`=(SELECT \`coins\` WHERE \`token\`='".$token."')-".$transfer." WHERE \`token\`='".$token."'";`

Comment: Ужасное решение. 1) вы плохо знакомы с синтаксисом SQL. перестаньте думать в терминах программирования "вот сюда я запишу значение, сюда его подставлю". 2) может получиться так, что первый запрос выполнится, сервер mysql умрет, тогда у кого-то появятся деньги, а у кого-то они НЕ спишутся. Решение - использовать транзакции.

Comment: @TotalPusher, Согласен, транзакции лучше, я попробую добавить их позднее.